# How to upgrade saaj-impl from 1.5.3 to 3.0.2?

Tags: java, soap, saaj

In a Java 11 project the `com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.saaj-impl` version 1.5.3 is used. I want to upgrade the project to the latest version, 3.0.2. However, when I do so, a test fails with a `SOAPException` with the message `javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SAAJ meta-factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl not found`. I've tried debugging the code, but it is unclear to me why the `SAAJMetaFactoryImpl` is missing. Why is the factory missing, what is going wrong here and how can I update the `saaj-impl` dependency?